# Creating a glue connection to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I currently have two glue connections. First connects to a db inside a private subnet (via a nat gateway in a public subnet). The connection is present in the private subnet. Now I created a redshift cluster in a public subnet and am trying to establish a connection via aws glue. however glue complains that there is no s2 endpoint on nat gateway associated with the public subnet. But this is the same public subnet which contains my nat gateway. I'm not able to understand why it is giving me this error and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html) regarding AWS GLue access to RedShift? Having redshift cluster in public subnet is not recommended.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a third party service to be picking up data from redshift and they don't have a way to connect via ssh

Comment: This documentation didn't help me and that's how I came here. Next thing I want to try is using a VPC endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

this may seem obvious but creating an S3 endpoint for the public subnet solved the issue. However, I'm still not able to understand why it didn't consider the NAT gateway.

Comment: Does the Redshift cluster have Enhanced VPC Routing enabled? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-routing.html

Comment: Nope. I didn't enable it.